# Memory leak in NSMutableArray allocation

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I am getting memory leak in NSMutableArray allocation.. in

```
NSMutableArray *contactsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

CODE:

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getContacts
{
    addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    NSArray* peopleArray =  (NSArray*) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    int noOfPeople = [peopleArray count];

    NSMutableArray *contactsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    for ( int i = 0; i < noOfPeople; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person =   [peopleArray objectAtIndex:i];
        ABRecordID personId = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
        NSString* personIdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", personId];

        ContactDTO* contactDTO = [AddressBookUtil getContactDTOForId:personIdStr];


        [contactsArray addObject:contactDTO];

    }
    [peopleArray release];
    return contactsArray;

}
```

Comment: This is the *fourth* memory leak question you've asked today.  You really should read the documentation on memory management at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: ... plus the one markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

It is standard procedure that objects returned from methods (in your case, contactsArray) are autoreleased before returning.
You could either `return [contactsArray autorelease];` or create it already autoreleased with `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:noOfPeople]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to release contactsArray manually somewhere, because it does not define autorelease.

Comment: I tried using autorelease at the allocation. but it is causing exception.I need to release the array with in that method. Can u suggest any other solution